# Java equivalent of C# DESCrypto

Tags: java, c#, cryptography, des

I have DESCrypto in C# and Java as follows. I get the correct results when using C#. I get problem when using Java. How to resolved this problem?

// This is in the main function which will call the crypto function in the security class (C#).

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    string plainText = "0123456789";
    Debug.WriteLine("plainText:" + plainText ); 
    // plainText:0123456789

    byte[] encrypted = Security.Encrypt(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainText));
    Debug.WriteLine("encrypted:" + Security.GetString(encrypted)); 
    // encrypted:4F792B474936462B6A4F62635A6142464D54782F4E413D3D

    byte[] decrypted = Security.Decrypt(encrypted);
    Debug.WriteLine("decrypted:" + Encoding.ASCII.GetString(decrypted)); //                               
    // decrypted:0123456789
}
```

// This is a security class (C#)

```
public class Security
{
    private static byte[] IV_64 = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    private static byte[] KEY_64 = new byte[] { 7, 1, 7, 7, 5, 5, 4, 7 };

    public static byte[] GetBytes(string value)
    {
        SoapHexBinary shb = SoapHexBinary.Parse(value);
        return shb.Value;
    }

    public static string GetString(byte[] value) 
    {
        SoapHexBinary shb = new SoapHexBinary(value);
        return shb.ToString();
    }

    public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] value)
    {
        MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(value)));
        CryptoStream cstream = new CryptoStream(mstream, new DESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateDecryptor(KEY_64, IV_64), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cstream);
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());
   }

    public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] value)
    {
        MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cstream = new CryptoStream(mstream, new DESCryptoServiceProvider().CreateEncryptor(KEY_64, IV_64), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(cstream);
        writer.Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(value));
        writer.Flush();
        cstream.FlushFinalBlock();
        mstream.Flush();
        return Encoding ASCII.GetBytes(Convert.ToBase64String(mstream.GetBuffer(), 0, Convert.ToInt32(mstream.Length)));
    }
}
```

// This is in the main function which will call the crypto function in the security class (Java).

```
String plainText = "0123456789";
Log.d("test", String.format("plainText:%s\n", plainText)); 
// plainText:0123456789

byte[] encrypted = Security.Encrypt(plainText.getBytes());
Log.d("test", String.format("encrypted:%s\n", Security.GetString(encrypted)));  
// encrypted:3B2F8623A17E8CE6DC65A045313C7F34

byte[] decrypted = Security.Decrypt(encrypted);
Log.d("test", String.format("decrypted: %s\n", String.valueOf(decrypted)));     
// decrypted:[B@6801b34
```

//This is a security class (JAVA)

```
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Security {
    private static byte[] IV_64 = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    private static byte[] KEY_64 = new byte[] { 7, 1, 7, 7, 5, 5, 4, 7 };

    private static String KEY_TYPE = "DES";
    private static String ALGORITHM = "DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding";

    public static String GetString(byte[] value) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte i : value) {
            builder.append(String.format("%02X", i & 0xff));
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public static byte[] GetByte(String value) {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (char i : value.toCharArray()) {
            builder.append(String.format("%02X", i & 0xff));
        }
        return String.valueOf(builder).getBytes();
    }

    public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] value) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(KEY_64, KEY_TYPE), new IvParameterSpec(IV_64));
            return cipher.doFinal(value);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] value) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(KEY_64, KEY_TYPE), new IvParameterSpec(IV_64));
            return cipher.doFinal(value);
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

In java, when `plainText = "0123456789"`, expected output from encryption is 4F792B474936462B6A4F62635A6142464D54782F4E413D3D (like in C#), but I get 3B2F8623A17E8CE6DC65A045313C7F34.

Comment: I add the java code. I get problem while convert C# to Java. Please help me. Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C#, you're encoding the ciphertext with Base64 inside of the `Security` class and then you encode it again with Hex outside of it. In Java, you're only doing the Hex encoding. You should stick to one encoding and not combine two.

---

Other considerations:

- DES should really not be used nowadays. It's rather easy to brute-force.
- If you use CBC mode, then you need to use a new and unpredictable IV every time (randomly generated). It doesn't have to be secret, so you can prepend it to the ciphertext and slice it off before decryption.
- You really should be thinking about adding authentication to the ciphertext. Otherwise, it may be possible to run a padding oracle attack in your system. Either use an authenticated mode like GCM or EAX, or use an [encrypt-then-MAC](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/202/13022) scheme with a strong MAC like HMAC-SHA256.